# Transforming a supply power

Tags: current, driver, math

For a recent project i need to power a certain element with .7 amps and 5 volts. my input power is 5 volts, but i need to calculate a circuit for decreasing current. I looked for answers on google and found nothing, so help is very much appreciated.
(component's resistance is 7.1 ohms)

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question simply doesn't make any sense at all. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: You ***do*** realize that you can safely connect a 5V, 10Amp supply to a device which requires 5V and 0.7A?

Comment: sorry im really new to this

Comment: Your input power is 5W? Or do you have a supply which can provide 5V?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need a circuit for decreasing current. Your 5v load will take at most 0.7A. Your 5v supply needs to provide at least 0.7A.